# Visual C++ Forms: Global Keydown

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have created a standard windows forms application in Visual Studio 2010.

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
   ...
}
```

I want to capture keydown events globally (if I am in an other application, my form shall react to keydowns too).

Haw can I implement the event listener?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a global hot key i guess. For that its needed an API call.

It tells you how to do it

Edit:

Sorry didnt noticed that you wanted the code on cpp.

here is the right link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2213/Beginner-s-Tutorial-Using-global-hotkeys